# Interpreting a regex

Tags: php, regex

I need help interpreting the meaning of a regular expression. I'm trying to understand to improve my skills with them...

The regular expression is:

```
`(?<!\\\\)u`
```

It is used in PHP with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: what do you mean by "reversing" ?

Comment: You mean as in "reverse engineer"?

Comment: I wonder if he means "negate"? And this isn't a trivial problem if that's what he means...

Comment: That's u not followed by \\ right? (notice this is not an answer)

Comment: By "reversing" I mean what this regex is doing (I'm trying to understand what this particual one does).

Comment: @cwallenpoole, no, it's a look-behind, not a look-ahead.

Comment: @Renesis D'oh. Oh well. Like I said, it wasn't an answer.

Comment: In the future, might I recommend [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means, "Find a `u` that is not preceded by `\\`." The `?<!` construct is the [negative  lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and the `\\` is an escaped `\`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!PATTERN)
```

is a negative look-behind, where **PATTERN** must not be found before the match following the group, which is a `\\` in this case. (I'm also going on the basis the the 4 `\` is used due to escaping necessary within a php string)

See also [this demo](http://regexr.com?2u77a) for a live example.